# A way to analyze on-page SEO of site through web based services, when it isn't published?

Tags: seo, seo-audit

What's the best way to analyze on-page SEO of a site through web based services, when that site is not in public, but on a development server, password protected?

In other words, how can I let web services analyze a web site but still let it stay unavailable for public (because of new design, new functionality that are still in tests)?

Comment: Those tools are usually useless.

Answer (score 3):

If they don't offer a way to provide authentication or for you to upload a static version of the site you can't unless you disable authentication while they do their scan.